# Delphi WSDL return nil

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, delphi, wsdl

I am new to dealing with the WSDL service and I am facing a problem in the response received from the service, and the technical details are:

1- Service is build with C# and the description from the .pas file :

```
  // Namespace : http://tempuri.org/
  // soapAction: http://tempuri.org/IService/%operationName%
  // transport : http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http
  // style     : document
  // use       : literal
  // binding   : BasicHttpBinding_IService
  // service   : Service
  // port      : BasicHttpBinding_IService
  // URL       : http://website.com/WCF/ServiceRegistryWCF.Service.svc

IService= interface(IInvokable)
```

2- the main object description from the .pas file :

```
  // XML       : InOut, global, <complexType>
  // Namespace : http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MySDK.Accomodation
  InOut2 = class(IBusinessObject2)
```

3- I call the service as follow:

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  HRIO: THTTPRIO;
procedure MyProcedure();
var
  ioObj: InOut2;
  res: string;
begin
  HRIO := THTTPRIO.Create(nil);
  HRIO.OnAfterExecute := THRIOActions.HTTPRIO1AfterExecute;
  HRIO.OnBeforeExecute := THRIOActions.HTTPRIO1BeforeExecute;
  HRIO.WSDLLocation := 'http://website.com/WCF/ServiceRegistryWCF.Service.svc?wsdl';
  HRIO.Service := 'Service';
  HRIO.Port := 'BasicHttpBinding_IService';
  HRIO.HTTPWebNode.InvokeOptions := [soIgnoreInvalidCerts, soAutoCheckAccessPointViaUDDI];
  HRIO.Converter.Options := HRIO.Converter.Options + [soDocument, soLiteralParams];
  HRIO.Converter.Encoding := 'utf-8';

  ioObj := InOut2.Create;
  ioObj.UserName := '1234567890';
  ioObj.Password := '123456';
  ioObj.InOutID := 123456789;

  res := (HRIO as IService).ProcedureName('password', ioObj, 0);
  memo1.lines.add(res);
end;
```

When I traced the process through the two procedures ("HTTPRIO1AfterExecute", "HTTPRIO1BeforeExecute") I found the result as follows:

The request text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ProcedureName xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <LocalPassword>password</LocalPassword>
            <io>
                <InOutID xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MySDK.Accomodation">
                    123456789
                </InOutID>
                <Password xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MySDK.Accomodation">
                    123456
                </Password>
                <UserName xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MySDK.Accomodation">
                    1234567890
                </UserName>
            </io>
            <language>0</language>
        </ProcedureName>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The response text:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <ProcedureNameResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <ProcedureNameResult i:nil="true" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
        </ProcedureNameResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

And the end result was:

```
<ProcedureNameResult xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" i:nil="true" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

But it must be either True or a text message in case an error occurs, and as you can see, the result is different than expected.

I apologize for the prolongation, but I tried to explain all possible details.

Comment: You are not getting any errors.  Your request is a query and no data with the search parameter are being found.  We are not going to be able to help.  I would first try a query to get all the ids in the database.  Then verify the ID you querying is actually in the database.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I know that I do not receive any error, but the result I get is the error, as I mentioned earlier, the result must be one of two options(True/ErrorMessage), and even if the IDs are not in the database, the service will return a message indicating that.

Comment: What I'm trying to check, are the settings in Step No3 correct, or have I missed something.

Comment: If the InOutID is not in the machine then you will get exactly the results you are getting.  So the code is good but the query parameters (username, password, id) are not matching any data.

Comment: I would try using something like [PostMan](http://www.postman.com) and see what response you get using the values from your request. That would at least confirm that your request is configured correctly. I don't have any connection to PostMan other than finding it a useful tool.